# Not allowed to access this page wp-admin page

Tags: php, wordpress

My website was https://www.example1.com now I have just replaced the siteurl with https://www.example2.com. My website is working fine with new url. but the problem is with wp-admin page. When I am accessing it, it is showing

```
Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.
```

If I just change the url it works fine again but not with new url.

Could you please tell me what is the mistake I am doing

Thanks in advance!

**Note: My website is on godaddy's plask server**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are all sorts of internal links in WordPress sites. When you migrate a site from one URL to another it's best to use a migration plugin. I like Duplicator, but there are others. The migration plugins fix up all the internal links and other stuff.

You may be trying to display a backend page from the old site, because some link or other did not get fixed.

And, don't forget to visit Settings / Permalinks and make sure the permalinks on your new setup are the same as on the old.

Comment: If no migration plugin is available, it's also useful to replace URL 1 with URL 2 in the MySQL client (e.g. phpMyAdmin).

Comment: Yes, you can do that. If the two URLs are *exactly* the same length, it works best. Otherwise you can hose some [serialized php objects](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) in various option and metadata values. I used to try to do that, but finally figured out it wasn't worth the trouble.